# How do I convert numbers into letter form, ex. 3 to three, and then className = three?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am making a dice roller. This code gives the sum of the dice rolled.

```
function getSumDiceValue(){
    var dice = diceWindowWrapper.getElementsByClassName("dice");
    var diceTotal = 0;                                                  
    for(var i = 0; i < dice.length; i++){                               
        diceTotal += Number(dice[i].getAttribute("data-diceValue"));    
    };

      return diceTotal;                                                 
    };
```

I want to set the class name of *zero* to the value of *getSumDiceValue()*, but in letters.

That is if I roll a 6 then the value of *getSumDiceValue()* is equal to 6, and then I want zero.className to equal six. That is:

```
zero.className = six;
```

Then I would need to "plug it in" to this code:

```
var zero = document.createElement("li");
zero.className = <here>;

diceToolbarCounterWrapper.appendChild(zero);
```

I think I need to make an array of some kind. But I am new to javaScript and not sure how I would go about doing that. Please add code to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've previously written a function for converting a integer number in the range
 `-999 999 999 999 999 ... 999 999 999 999 999` to it's full English name (short scale)

```
var numberWord = (function () {
    var words = [
        'zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four',
        'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine',
        'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen',
        'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen'
    ];
    words.length = 99;
    var i, j, tens = [
        '', '', 'twenty', 'thirty', 'forty',
        'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety'
    ];
    for (i = 2; i < 10; ++i) {
        words[10 * i] = tens[i];
        for (j = 1; j < 10; ++j) {
            words[10 * i + j] = tens[i] + ' ' + words[j];
        }
    }
    var power = [
        {e: 1e2, str: 'hundred', and: false},
        {e: 1e3, str: 'thousand', and: false},
        {e: 1e6, str: 'million', and: false},
        {e: 1e9, str: 'billion', and: false},
        {e: 1e12, str: 'trillion', and: false},
    ];
    function strAdd(a, b) {
        if (a && b) return a + ' ' + b;
        return a || b || '';
    }
    function strAndAdd(a, b) {
        if (a && b) return a + ' and ' + b;
        return a || b || '';
    }
    return function numberWord(x) {
        var number = '';
        x = Math.floor(x);
        if (x !== x) return 'NaN';
        if (x === 0) return words[0];
        if (x < 0) {
            number = strAdd(number, 'minus');
            x = Math.abs(x);
        }
        if (x > 999999999999999) throw new RangeError('Number must be in -999999999999999..999999999999999');
        var i = power.length - 1, j, substr;
        for (; i >= 0; --i) {
            if (x >= power[i].e) {
                j = Math.floor(x / power[i].e);
                substr = numberWord(j) + ' ' + power[i].str;
                if (power[i].and) number = strAndAdd(number, substr);
                else number = strAdd(number, substr);
                x %= power[i].e;
            }
        }
        if (x > 0) {
            number = strAndAdd(number, words[x]);
        }
        return number;
    }
}());
```

Example usage

```
numberWord(+'-999,999,999,999,999'.replace(/,/g, ''));
// "minus nine hundred and ninety nine trillion nine hundred and ninety nine billion nine hundred and ninety nine million nine hundred and ninety nine thousand nine hundred and ninety nine"

numberWord(1999); // "one thousand nine hundred and ninety nine"
numberWord(2016); // "two thousand and sixteen"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this function. It get a numeric value as parameter and returnes this number as text. (Numbers 1 to 6 for the dice):

```js
var diceResult = 6;

var getNumberText = function(num) {
  //Create an object that maps the relation between numeric and literal values of numbers
  var numTxtSet = {    
    1: 'one',
    2: 'two',
    3: 'three',
    4: 'four',
    5: 'five',
    6: 'six'
  }
  //Check if the given parameter is a number
  if (num && !isNaN(num)) {
    return numTxtSet[num];
  }
}

//Call the function passing 'diceResult' as parameter and store it's value to a variable
var res = getNumberText(diceResult);
alert(res);
```

Comment: To "plug" this code into my dice roller. I first need to set: " var DiceResult = getSumDiceValue(); "

And also set :" zero.className = res; " do I need to add an event listener so that the counter updates when I add a new dice?

Answer (score 0):

In case your getSumDiceValue() function, will be returning a numeric value, of a range from 0 to 6, you might be after something like this:

```
var numTxtSet = "zero,one,two,three,four,five,six".split(",");
zero.className = numTxtSet[ getSumDiceValue() ];
```

Comment: I have a button to add, and a button to remove dice, would I have to add an event listener to these buttons to update the counter? In that case, what would the code look like for that?

Comment: the plan is to be able to add multiple dice. If the summ of the dice is 12, then I would want to be able to split the number up into two, and shown over 2 different *zero classes* So I would have: zero.className = one | zero.classname = two.

Comment: but than you'll need to re-clarify your question at the top. This is a different situation. The code provided on my answer will do exactly what required from the way you've described the problem. It is not clear why the assignment of `document.createElement("li");` is being returned to a variable named 'zero'.

Comment: How would you phrase my question? I have a button to add a die, I have a button to remove a die. When I add a die I want the counter to display the value of the dice. How do I keep the counter up to date?(using your code) surely there is a way in which I can just use .slice on the value "12" so that the first "zero" only uses the number 1, and the second "zero" uses only the number 2.